# Cannot apply css style of material input with datepicker

Tags: css, angular-material, datepicker

I can’t correctly implement a datepicker in my application in css style. I don’t understand what’s wrong.

The datepicker icon and date are incorrectly positioned in my application (gives screenshots below).

Here's code:

HTML:

```
<div class="date-from-field">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="dateTo" />
    <mat-hint>DD/MM//YYYY</mat-hint>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle
      matIconSuffix
      [for]="picker"
    ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Module imports:

```
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule
  ]
```

angular.json:

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles/main.scss",
              "./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-spinner/animations/ball-scale-multiple.css"
            ],
```

This is the rendering I get in the appication:

[image]

Instead of in the material doc:

[image]

Thanks for help